# Linear transformations with inverses.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, definition

I am using Evar Nering's and Bernard Kolman's linear algebra texts.

"automorphisms are the only linear transformations with inverses." Nering.

"Theorem 6.7: Let $L:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Then $L$ is invertible if and only if $L$ is one-to-one and onto." Kolman.

Nering did not provide a proof. My issue is I think not all one-to-one and onto linear transformations are automorphisms. Am I missing something here?

Comment: An automorphism is a map from one object to **itself**. If $V\ne W$ then $L:V\to W$ might be an isomorphism, but never an automorphism.

Comment: I know that. So it seems the statement from Nering's text is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The statement “automorphisms are the only linear transformations with inverse” is about automorphisms, but theorem 6.7 isn't. You seem to be suggesting that they are in conflict, but they are about different things. But, yes, you are right when you assert that not all one-to-one and onto linear transformations (between *possibly distinct vector spaces*) are automorphisms. And… ?

Comment: it is because Nering used the word "**only**" which is what makes me think that it's incorrect.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Why? The you know some invertible map (linear or not) which is *not* ono-to-one and onto?

Comment: I meant that there are other one-to-one and onto linear transformations that are **not** automorphisms which are invertible. Which is the opposite of "automorphisms are the only linear transformations with inverses."

Comment: I see. Well, you do have a point there.

Comment: It might be a typo. thank you anyways.